# Using AbstractProjectConfig in Android project

Tags: android, kotest

I am trying to set a global project configuration for Kotest.  I have followed the instructions at https://kotest.io/project_config/

However, I have a number of unresolved items in the below:

```
package io.kotest.provided

import io.kotest.core.config.AbstractProjectConfig

object ProjectConfig : AbstractProjectConfig() {
    override val assertionMode = AssertionMode.Error
}
```

Where, in the import statement, `core` is unresolved.

`AbstractProjectConfig` is unresolved.

`AssertionMode` is unresolved.

So then of course, `assertionMode` "overrides nothing" as well

In my app-level build.gradle, I have

```
dependencies {

[...]

    testImplementation 'io.kotest:kotest-runner-junit5:4.3.1' // for kotest framework
    testImplementation 'io.kotest:kotest-assertions-core:4.3.1' // for kotest core jvm assertions
    testImplementation 'io.kotest:kotest-property:4.3.1' // for kotest property test
}

android.testOptions {
    unitTests.all {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
}
```

Is it possible to use `AbstractProjectConfig` within an Android project?  If so, where have I gone wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that the kotest documentation is slightly misleading (I have filed an issue: https://github.com/kotest/kotest/issues/1866).  I have found that the dependencies needed in my app-level build.gradle are of the form:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation("io.kotest:kotest-runner-junit5-jvm:<version>")
    androidTestImplementation("io.kotest:kotest-runner-junit5-jvm:<version>") {
        exclude(module: "objenesis")
    }
    androidTestImplementation("io.kotest:kotest-assertions-core-jvm:<version>")
```

As given in the sample app at https://github.com/kotest/kotest-android-samples/blob/master/app/build.gradle

Referring to those shown at https://kotest.io/quick_start/#gradle there are a few key differences:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'io.kotest:kotest-runner-junit5:<version>' // for kotest framework
    testImplementation 'io.kotest:kotest-assertions-core:<version>' // for kotest core jvm assertions
    testImplementation 'io.kotest:kotest-property:<version>' // for kotest property test
}
```

Note that the sample-app dependencies work, those in the docs do not.

i.e. the suffix `-jvm` is required, and in some cases `androidTestImplementation` is required rather than `testImplementation`.  I'm new to testing and Android and this wasn't obvious to me, so apologies if this is something that someone more experienced would have worked out at a glance!